# reinforcement learning: Decompose a policy gradient

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I am studying the policy gradient through the website: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-actor-critic-methods-931b97b6df3f

Couldn't figure out how the first equation becomes the second equation?

In the second equation, why the first Expectation value have only s_0, a_0, s_1, a_1 ... s_t, a_t but no reward involved? Also, the second Expectation Value has only r_t+1, s_t+1, ... r_T, s_T, but no action involved? Could anyone please share the thoughts/intuition behind this? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Medium post has brackets in the wrong place . . . the second expectation **must** be inside the sum to make sense, otherwise $t$ is not defined. You can see a couple of steps later that $Q(s_t, a_t)$ gets magically moved back inside the sum.

I cannot see a way to fix the first expectation though that uses $t$ *before* it is defined!

The expectations are trying to show which parts of the distribution of trajectories each calculation *explicitly* depends upon. I don't think you need to read into it anything more than that.

However, I would suggest you find another article which does not have these errors. There are similar derivations of Policy Gradient in [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html)